# Generating a header tag using XStream

Tags: java, jaxb, xstream

I am using XStream utility to convert the POJOs to XML.

But when I generate a xml and try to read it for further processing, it throws an error

```
Exception caused by : com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
```

To solve this, I googled and found it was missing the header tag of xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

How do I add the header like above while converting the Java object to XML file?

Answer (score 5):

Just add manually:

```
public static final String XML_HEADER = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";

public String toXML() {
    return XML_HEADER + xStream.toXML(this);
}
```